# Display both image and text from array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a lightbox in React that loops over an array of objects but I can't seem to get both the image and text to display. Ultimately I want each image to have text over it just identifying each pest.

The error is that I am  getting empty objects on the page. I am sure i am doing something incredibly dumb ;)

```
[object Object]
```

Might anyone have any insight on how to get this working or if there's something I am missing? Thanks in advance.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Ant from '../../img/ant.jpeg';
import Bee from '../../img/bee.jpeg';
import Bedbug from '../../img/bedbug.jpeg';
import Wasp from '../../img/wasp.jpeg';
import Mouse from '../../img/mouse.jpeg'

// const images = [Bee, Ant, Bedbug, Wasp, Mouse];

const images_arr = [
  { image: Ant, text: "Ant" },
  { image: Bee, text: "Bee" },
  { image: Bedbug, text: "Bedbug" },
  { image: Mouse, text: "Mice" },
  { image: Wasp, text: "Wasp" },
]

console.log(images_arr)
function PestsGallery() {
  const [imageToShow, setImageToShow] = useState("");
  const [lightboxDisplay, setLightBoxDisplay] = useState(false);

  //looping through our images array to create img elements
  const imageCards = images_arr.map((image, text) => (
    <img key={image} alt={image} className="image-card" onClick={() => showImage(image)} src={image} />
  ));

  const showImage = (image, text) => {
    setImageToShow(image);
    setLightBoxDisplay(true)
  }

  const hideLightBox = () => {
    setLightBoxDisplay(false)
  }

  const showNext = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let currentIndex = images_arr.indexOf(imageToShow);
    if (currentIndex >= images_arr.length - 1) {
      setLightBoxDisplay(false)
    } else {
      let nextImage = images_arr[currentIndex + 1];
      setImageToShow(nextImage)
    }
  }

  const showPrev = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let currentIndex = images_arr.indexOf(imageToShow);
    if (currentIndex <= 0) {
      setLightBoxDisplay(false);
    } else {
      let nextImage = images_arr[currentIndex - 1];
      setImageToShow(nextImage);
    }
  };
```

Here's the return statement and the rest

```
 return (
    <>
      <h2> Bugs we treat</h2>
      <div>{imageCards}</div>
      {
        lightboxDisplay ?
          <div id="lightbox" onClick={hideLightBox}>
            <button onClick={showPrev}>⭠</button>
            <img alt="gallery" id="lightbox-img" src={imageToShow}></img>
            <button onClick={showNext}>⭢</button>
          </div>
          : ""
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default PestsGallery;
```

Comment: You're looping thru an array of objects. I think you meant to destructure the object when you're passing it into the loop, you need curly braces for that

Comment: const imageCards = images_arr.map((image, text)  -> needs to be:   const imageCards = images_arr.map(({image, text})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to destructure the values of the object when mapping. You need to change this:

```
const imageCards = images_arr.map((image, text) => (
    <img key={image} alt={image} className="image-card" onClick={() => showImage(image)} src={image} />
  ));
```

to this:

```
const imageCards = images_arr.map(({image, text}) => (
    <img key={image} alt={image} className="image-card" onClick={() => showImage(image)} src={image} />
  ));
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's resolved. How silly of me. Only issue now is that I am seeing a blank image when I go through the lightbox, the images are blank.